# how to create token in dotnet 5.0 Using WS-Federation without ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, token, ws-federation

I had to use WS-Federation without ASP.NET Core Identity in my dot net 5.0 project. I have set up my startup file referring below official document from Microsoft. I am not sure how we should create token based on claims / principal after user authentication.

Target Framework - Dot Net 5.0
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how we should create token based on claims / principal after user authentication.

As far as I know, the WS-Federation is a authentication provider like Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) or Azure Active Directory (AAD).

It will generate the token and we use this token to access the resources which is protected by the asp.net core.

After you authenticate from the WS-Federation provider, it will generate the token and this token contains the claims or else and you could use this token to access the WS-Federation provider protected resource like your web api which you have add the codes from the article.

The article you have provided is also using the Oauth, I suggest you could read to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) to understand how Oauth works.